# Forcing computer keypress through browser tech

Tags: javascript, c#, browser

Is it possible to force an actual keypress through a browser?

So say if i want to click on a button on the browser and then the pc reacts to it and press for an example presses alt+tab

Comment: @Icemanind that's actually quite irrelevant as the question is whether there are client-side APIs, freely translating *browser tech*, for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully not. The amount of sites that would run `win-r format c:\` would run in the millions within a day of this being possible. Or cool Linux stuff like `cat /etc/passwd /etc/shadow | mail h4ck3rb0y@gmail.com`.

A browser is **heavily** *sandboxed*, meaning it can do nothing at all outside the browser's context without explicit API's exposing it, and the user allowing it. No API's exist (thankfully, again) for destroying one's computer remotely.

Comment: So how about if the user allowing it would it be possible with any API's this is for certain not going to be used in any malware connection

Comment: No, as said no API's exist that could endanger any client computer in any way. Thankfully, again.

Comment: Things like Java apps and browser plugins can provide a little more control over the local computer.

Comment: Mike i just need to be able to press 4 buttons on the website that control the arrow key :P therefore i would hope there is some solution for that, and niels are your sure not even with a Java implementation on the website?

Comment: where do you want the arrow key to be pressed? inside the browser, no problem, on notepad or calc, big problem...

Comment: Even in browsers that still support Java applets (Chrome for example does **not**) the security requirements have been risen to extremely high.  If you disable all of those on the Java end and the browser end you may be able to get this code working in IE up to v11. That would mean it could work on a single very badly configured PC. And if you write that much Java code for use in a single PC you might as well just build a desktop GUI program with 4 buttons and that code, skipping the browser altogether.

Comment: The thing is it has to simply run from the browser for relatively easy connection and yes dandavis it has to trigger outside browser events :) but i just can't seem to figure a way to make it smarter. The idea was if you have a phone and u want to make a game controler for example mario and you have to make the connectivity to the pc through a websocket or a browser link like kahoot does how would u create such a thing? :)

Comment: I think a web app is just not the right solution for what you're trying to do..  I'd take a step back and rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers guys and we will reconsider tge way of approaching it then :)